# Error trying to compile C++, OpenGL and Emscripten on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, emscripten

I'm trying to configure Emscripten and OpenGL on Visual Studio 2010.
Emscripten and OpenGL are working fine separated.
When I'm trying to compile an OpenGL example with Emscripten I get linker error -

> GCCLINK : error root: opengl32.lib: No such file or directory ("opengl32.lib" was expected to be an input file, based on the commandline arguments provided)

anybody?

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the Library directory where to find opengl32.lib in the project linker settings

Comment: I did that for each of the libraries -opengl32.lib;freeglut.lib;glew32.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib , but it still making errors. It seems to me like Emscripten is not able to read the system libraries.

Comment: The error is simply that the linker does not find the file. You have to specify not only the Input files, but also unter Linker->General->Additional Library Directories where these lib files are.